React Native Expo: "Element type is invalid" error when using expo-camera in QrScanner component
In this code I had errors:

Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
2.Warning: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

I'm using:
"expo": "^52.0.7",
"expo-camera": "~16.0.5",
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Alert, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Camera } from 'expo-camera';

const QrScanner = () => {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
  const [orderDetails, setOrderDetails] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getCameraPermissions = async () => {
      try {
        const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
        setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while requesting camera permissions:', error);
      }
    };

    getCameraPermissions();
  }, []);

  const handleBarcodeScanned = ({ type, data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    try {
      const decodedData = JSON.parse(data); // Assuming QR code contains JSON
      setOrderDetails(decodedData);
      Alert.alert('Success', 'QR code scanned successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error parsing QR code data:', error);
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Invalid data format in QR code.');
    }
  };

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <Text style={styles.message}>Requesting for camera permission...</Text>;
  }

  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text style={styles.message}>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Camera
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarcodeScanned}
        style={styles.camera}
      />
      {scanned && (
        <Button
          title="Scan Again"
          onPress={() => setScanned(false)}
        />
      )}
      {orderDetails && (
        <View style={styles.detailsContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.label}>Order Details:</Text>
          <Text style={styles.value}>Name: {orderDetails.orderName}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.value}>
            Location: {orderDetails.locationName}, {orderDetails.cityName}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.value}>Category: {orderDetails.categoryType}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.value}>Number of Tickets: {orderDetails.numberOfTickets}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.value}>Total Price: {orderDetails.grandTotal} zł</Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // ... your styles
});

export default QrScanner;


